# socketcan alternative / add can0 to /dev/

Tags: linux, ubuntu, can-bus, socketcan

I am currently working with CAN-BUS Systems.

I make the CAN Interface available using

```
sudo modprobe can
sudo modprobe can-raw
sudo modprobe mttcan
sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 250000
sudo ip link set up can0
```

It now shows up in `ifconfig` and works fine in my python code.

Since I am working with aws greengrass I need the device to show up in /dev/ in order to access it. Is there any way to use something different than socketcan? If so, how do I use it?

I have no idea how linux handles can interfaces.

Comment: Have you already a solution for your Problem? I have the same Problem with the PiCan3 and Docker

Comment: I worked around it by disabling containerazation in greengrass. Not a pretty solution, but it worked